Error calling initialize function: TypeError: program.methods.x is not a function, but x IS a function
So, I'm facing an extremely confusing error.
I have a solana anchor program, with 5 functions:
{ // console.log(program.methods)
  initialize: [Function (anonymous)],
  initiateSwapErc20: [Function (anonymous)],
  initiateSwapNative: [Function (anonymous)],
  ReceiveNative: [Function (anonymous)],
  ReceiveErc20: [Function (anonymous)]
}

In a typescript script, I'm calling
initialize like this:
const txHash = await program.methods.initialize(...).accounts(...).rpc();
It works.
I call InitiateSwapNative like this:
const txHash = await program.methods.initiateSwapNative(...).accounts(...).rpc();
It works.
But, when I call ReceiveNative, like this, so exactly the same:
const txHash = await program.methods.ReceiveNative(...).accounts(...).rpc();
I get the following typescsript error:
Error calling initialize function: TypeError: program.methods.ReceiveNative is not a function
Know that I call this function right after printing program.methods that output that ReceiveNative is a function.
HOWEVER, when I simply change my function name to whatever, this is not an issue anymore. So I'm guessing it have to do something with the name itself, maybe the name resolve to a forbidden hash or something... I have no idea
FYI:
The function:
pub fn receive_native(ctx: Context<ReceiveNative>
The instruction:
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct ReceiveNative<'info> {
    #[account(seeds = [b"state_account"], bump)]
    pub state_account: Box<Account<'info, StateAccount>>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"program_token_account"],
        bump,
    )]
    pub program_token_account: SystemAccount<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user_token_account: SystemAccount<'info>,

    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}


This is very odd. The name program.methods.ReceiveNative doesn't seem like any function that would exist in TS - JS/TS functions are named in camelCase unless they're constructors.
Your Rust function is probably called recieve_native(), and the Accounts struct (you have pasted above) is called RecieveNative because that's how Rust names structs.
Anchor converts Rust names to JS/TS names, so the recieve_native() Rust function name SHOULD be program.methods.receiveNative(). What version of Anchor are you using?

You might also want to show the actual instruction, rather than just the Struct, to help us debug.

I've found the issue. In my original post, I changed the name of the instruction (because of non disclosure agreement, I can't post the actual name).
The function name was something like abc1def_receive_native
It will compile as abc1defReceiveNative in the idl and the types, BUT, in typescript, two weird things happen:
program.methods output abc1DefReceiveNative with an uppercase D (???) as a function
BUT, when actually using abc1DefReceiveNative as function, it doesn't compile typescript.
So, somehow,
abc1defReceiveNative exist during compilation, but not during runtime
abc1DefReceiveNative exist during runtime, but not during compilation
I will probably open an issue on anchor's lang github to reference
